# Web Server - How to execute PHP script when accessing a file?

Tags: php, web-services, web, modx

I would like to run a PHP code when a file on the web server is accessed (e.g. /../../somefile.pdf).

I need to display a disclaimer when a user access the website for the first time. I made this possible executing a PHP script every time a webpage is accessed but I don't know how to run the script when a file instead is accessed of a webpage.
Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this for Evolution or Revolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to track downloads, there are two ways:

1. Change the download URL to go via a PHP file i.e. instead of `<a href="/../../somefile.pdf">..</a>` try `<a href="/download.php?file=/../../somefile.pdf">..</a>`
2. Use rewrite in .htaccess (Apache Rewrite mod) to redirect the download URL to a PHP file first, for example:
   `RewriteRule ^download_directory/(.*)$ /download.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]`

In your file, download.php you have two options again:

1. Read the file using the Path in the `file` param, and use PHP to echo the output. (This method is insecure as the user may modify the path in the `file` param and get a file he is not supposed to access.)
2. Since your files are in the webroot (i.e. they can be access directly) it is best to redirect the user to the actual file once your tracking code completes execution using `header('Location: ' . $_GET['file']);`

Comment: If I use rewrite in .htaaccess, do I get an infinite cycle?  

`header('Location: ' . $_GET['file'])` will redirect me to the same URL that was rewrited.
Or I'm misunderstanding something..

Comment: Yes it is possible. Try adding a special param when you are redirecting from PHP to the file which does not trigger the rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late for the original author, but this is what MODX [Static Resources](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Static+Resource) are perfect for.

Static resources are an abstraction of a real file hosted on your server, and would allow you in this instance to execute the same snippet/plugin you're already using in the same way you are for standard web page requests. No .htaccess mods or custom headers required.

More info:

- [MODX Static Resources](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Static+Resource)
- [Static Resource / download PDF](http://forums.modx.com/index.php?topic=44920)